# Android cordovaLib project will not build - missing CordovaPreferences

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am to make edits to an existing cordova hybrid app. The android source code has 2 projects - one for cordova and one that is the app. The app project is saying that the cordova project isn't ready (repeated clean/builds of both didn't help), so I tried opening only the cordova project.

The cordova project (I am in eclipse 4.4.1) won't build and the errors (84) are saying that a bunch of class names can't be resolved to a type AND that sevearal classes cannot find CordovaPreferences

```
The method getPreferences() from the type Config refers to the missing type CordovaPreferences  CordovaWebView.java

The method getPreferences() from the type CordovaWebView refers to the missing type CordovaPreferences  PluginManager.java

The method getPreferences() from the type CordovaWebView refers to the missing type CordovaPreferences  PluginManager.java
```

My gut feeling is that I was not given all the source code.  That there's another library or project where CordovaPreferences is and I simply don't have it.

Any ideas on how I can get the cordova project to build?

NOTES:

- no import statements are underlined indicating there is a problem there.
- the /gen and /src directories are in the build path

The other errors I mentioned are like this for a few examples

```
CordovaUriHelper cannot be resolved to a type   CordovaWebViewClient.java

CordovaPreferences cannot be resolved to a type CordovaWebView.java 

ConfigXmlParser cannot be resolved to a type    Config.java

ConfigXmlParser cannot be resolved to a type    CordovaActivity.java
```

Any ideas on how I can get the cordova project to build.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a missing library problem rather than a missing source code problem, specifically the Cordova library. Is the Cordova .jar file on your JDK classpath (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html), or in the libs directory of your project?